# How to upload RDF into same Graph IRI using Virtuoso 7.1

Tags: rdf, virtuoso

I have two files.
One is `aaa.nt`, and another one is `bbb.ttl`.

I am trying to upload all the triples in the two files into one Graph IRI (`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`).

Actually I tried twice.
First, I failed, but the second time, I got it.

First way is as below.

In `iSQL`,

1. `ld_dir('/home/temp','*.nt','http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');`
2. `rdf_loader_run();`
3. `ld_dir('/home/temp','*.ttl','http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');`
4. `rdf_loader_run();`

Second  way is as below.

In `iSQL`,

1. `delete from load_list;`  # <-- for making `load_list` clear...
2. `ld_dir('/home/temp','*.nt','http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');`
3. `ld_dir('/home/temp','*.ttl','http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');`
4. `rdf_loader_run();`

Anyway, I succeeded with the second way above, but I don't understand the mechanism.

Using first way, I just get triples only from both files (`aaa.nt`, `bbb.ttl`).
I don't remember exactly, the triples I got was only from one of the files.

Using second way, I could get all triples in the two files.

What if I have a situation to add more triples using another `.nt` file. and upload into the same Graph IRI, which is `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`?

Am I doing something wrong?

Please let me know how to take care of it.

Thank you.

Comment: "Virtuoso 7.1" covers a number of sub-versions. Please include full output of `virtuoso-t -?` changed as necessary for your local binary name.

Comment: Without clear statement of the results of your first command sequence, it's very difficult to know what went wrong, nor how or why.  My best guess, knowing that you didn't copy-and-paste your commands here, is that you had a typo somewhere.

Comment: For future, such Virtuoso-specific questions often get faster response from the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the [public OpenLink support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or a [confidential Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).  (ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Answer (score 0):

Both methods should work i.e. your can load datasets either at the same time or separately in the Virtuoso Quad Store using the RDF Bulk loader function . We do both all the time ...